# Accessing value in forloop

Tags: errors, counters, loops, foreach

This code is not compiling and creates an error "Missing number, treated as zero".

```
\newcounter{x}
\forloop{x}{0}{\value{x} < 5}{
    value is \value{x} \\
}
```

How can the value of x be printed from inside the for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{x}
\forloop{x}{0}{\value{x}<5}{\noindent value is \arabic{x}\\}

\end{document}
```

You can also print the numbers as strings (zero, one, two , ...), if you load the `fmtcount` package and instead of `\arabic{x}` you can use `\numberstring{x}`.